# TimeZone parameter in postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

postgresql documentation says:

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
>   are converted to local time in the zone specified by the timezone
>   configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

timezone parameter is a [session parameter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE). When all `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`s will be stored as `UTC` and the client connection will specify the session timezone, then what is the benefit of setting TimeZone parameter in postgresql.conf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like with any other parameter that *can* be defined for every session, the setting in `postgresql.conf` is the **default** in the absence of an explicit setting for the session.